# Split array by number in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to separate a string from where the number is starting.

```
String uri = "/api/content/9011";
String[] splitUri = uri.split("[0-9]");
System.out.println(splitUri[0]);
System.out.println(splitUri[1]);
```

When i run this code it shows me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, can some one tell me why? I want to store at 0th index =/api/content/
and at 1st index= 9011. I even want first number inclusive. What should i do ??

Comment: what if your String is `"/api/content/9011/aaa/55/vvv"` what the output should look like?

Comment: String will be /api/content/{id} it wont be anything apart from this. so the number should be separated from the string @YCF_L

Comment: Read the JavaDoc of the split method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String). The split method splits **around** the matched regex. The regex will therefor not be part of the splitted array. (a:b splitted by : returns a, b. Not a,:,b)

Comment: Anyway. If your string really allways has the form /api/content/{id} the simplest way to extract the number would be: uri.substring(13)

Comment: If your string will always be of the form /api/content/{id} and you want to separate "/api/content/" and "{id}", you can simply do String s1 = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1); String s2 = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

Answer (score 6):

Do like this:

```
String line = "/api/content/9011";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(/api/content/)([0-9]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Remembering to `import java.util.regex.*;`

---

If you really need to do this with `split()`:

```
String uri = "/api/content/9011";
String[] splitUri = uri.split("(?<=\\/)(?=[0-9])");
System.out.println(splitUri[0]);
System.out.println(splitUri[1]);
```

But, please, read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) how a split works.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occures because the returned `array` from the split-method has just one entry. Through your regex you are "erasing"the numbers.
Split creates an `array` but will not add empty entries if there is no entry after them. Just debug with `String uri = "/api/content/9011a";` and you'll get an array of length 5:

1. /api/content/
2. ""
3. ""
4. ""
5. a

So as regex you should use `"(?<=\\/)(?=[0-9])"`. It uses lookahead and lookbehind as explained [here](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
 String uri = "/api/content/9011";
 String[] splitUri = uri.split("/");
 System.out.println(splitUri[0]); // ""
 System.out.println(splitUri[1]); // api
 System.out.println(splitUri[2]); // content
 System.out.println(splitUri[3]); // 9011
```